# Out of memory in maven on unpriviledged user

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, centos, out-of-memory

I am experiencing strange maven problem when running our maven tests on a CentOS box. The thing is, when I run

```
mvn install
```

as **unpriviledged user**, it hangs forever with following exception

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:713)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.launchLastDitchDaemonShutdownThread(ForkedBooter.java:181)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.exit(ForkedBooter.java:141)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.exit(ForkedBooter.java:141)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:125)

Exception in thread "main" Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native threadjava.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:713)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.launchLastDitchDaemonShutdownThread(ForkedBooter.java:181) at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.launchLastDitchDaemonShutdownThread(ForkedBooter.java:181)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.exit(ForkedBooter.java:141)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:133)

Exception in thread "metrics-meter-tick-thread-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:713)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:949)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processWorkerExit(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1017)  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:949)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processWorkerExit(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1017)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1163)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

However if I run the mvn as **root**, there's no problem.
Also, on an Ubuntu box as **unpriviledged user**, the tests run fine.

My Stack:

- Maven occurs both on 3.0.5 and 3.1.1
- CentOS 6.5 kernel 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64
- Ubuntu 13.10 kernel 3.11.0-15-generic
- JDK 1.7.0_51 (both on ubuntu and CentOS)

All is pretty much vanilla.

Other facts:

- $MAVEN_OPTS are not set in any shell (either CentOS or Ubuntu). I did try combinations of MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dmaven.surefire.debug=-Xmx3000m" but with same result
- $JAVA_OPTS are not set in any shell neither. I tried similar options as above, and since it had no effect, I dropped it.
- tried to parametrize the surefire plugin in ~/.m2 directory for every user I tried but without any result, so I dropped the config.
- from pstree I see the maven's java creates forks to ~1060 procsses in all cases.

Can somebody please explain what's going on.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: ***unable to create new native thread***

This is the important part. OutOfMemoryError has been expanded to mean 'cannot allocate some basic resource'. In this case, new threads, not memory.

Probable explanation: your 'ulimit' on the number of threads is smaller for a regular user than for root. When you went to a new Linux, it had a larger maximum for regular users.

I found this question because the "metrics-meter-tick-thread-1" threads are causing me major grief- a (Cassandra) library is creating these over and over again and I have 300 threads named "metrics-meter-tick-thread-1" and "metrics-meter-tick-thread-2".

Answer (score 1):

I have a setup similar to yours, except that I'm running on CentOS 6.4 and I'm using jdk 1.6. In order to get Maven to work on largish builds I had to set

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms256M -Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M"
```

I put this and other Maven related settings in a `mvn.sh` file in the `/etc/profile.d` directory, as I'm using bash.

Comment: This option work only if the maven installation also is exported.  But  you get upvote from me

Comment: Can't you add this setting to your own .profile/.bashrc or whatever? Actually as you have a private Maven installation it might be more convenient to directly modify the `mvn` script.

Comment: Note that I have a feeling that specifying *too much* memory doesn't help, even though I can't see a reason for that.

Comment: Thanks Nicola, but I've tried this settings previously, tried again now, no luck. BTW the machine has 12GB RAM and still has 6GB free as per free -m

Comment: I originally thought I might be hitting some adress space limit, but later I discovered I'm able to run this as root on the same machine, and on ubuntu. A mystery...

Answer (score 0):

Well not exactly an answer...

I finally moved to Ubuntu server and everything is running smootly. I repeat, both installations are vanilla, out-of-the-box, no customization (doesn't mean I didn't try any). I reinstalled the CentOS box twice to make sure I didn't left any misconguration. So for our tests, I wouldn't recommend CentOS for maven...

Feel free to answer anyway if you have any thoughts on what's going on. I can change the accepted answer anytime.